# Construction of K(G,1) from Hatcher.

Tags: algebraic-topology

[image]

1.For "each point $x\in[g_0, ··· , g_n]$ along the line segment in $[e, g_0, ··· , g_n]$ from $x$ to the vertex $[e]$", I wonder what if some $g_i=e$ (for example $g_0=e$ or $g_1=e$)? Actually, I don't know what $[e, e, ··· , g_n]$ is.

2. The points in $[g_0,g_1]$ (except $g_0,g_1$) are not elements of $G$, right?
3. I can't see why $h_t$ carries $[e]$ around the loop $[e,e]$, actually, I don't know what the $[e,e]$ is, where the loop is.

Comment: A simplex may be degenerate, some spanning vertices may coincide.

Comment: @Alejo, so the points in $[g_0,g_1]$ (except $g_0,g_1$) are not elements of $G$?

Comment: Not really. What is actually going on is that one builds a *simplicial set* and then the space with points is its *geometric realization*. If I remember well, this is not explained well by Hatcher.

Comment: @Alejo, but what if $G=Z_2$, there are only two elements of $G$, say $e,g_0$, what are the points in $[e,g_0]$?

Comment: A nice exposition: http://www.math.jhu.edu/~eriehl/ssets.pdf BG as a simplicial set is the nerve of G considered as a category, and the geometric realization |BG| is the K (G,1) space.

Comment: $[g_0, g_1]$ are simplices in the abstract simplicial set, they have no points. It is the geometric realization that is a topological space. It's better to read some proper text on simplicial sets, Hatcher's exposition is confusing.

Comment: @Alejo, Thank you, I have a question, for a simplex $[v_0, ··· , v_n]$, is that possible for some $v_i$s are the same?

Comment: Yes, it is still a (degenerate) n-simplex.

Comment: @Alejo, but Hatcher said: An equivalent condition would be that the difference vectors v1 − v0, ··· , vn − v0 are linearly independent, if so then what I said can not happen.

Comment: In a simplicial set, degenerate simplices are legitimate simplices. In the geometric realization, they are not visible and you can discard them when you calculate simplicial homology. Long story short: it's easier to read about simplicial sets than to make sense of Hatcher's exposition.

Comment: @Alejo Thank you for your patience! I feel appreciated.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Construction of K(G,1) space](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2344091/construction-of-kg-1-space)